# No module named tqdm after a pip install

Tags: python-3.x, tqdm

I'm trying to use tqdm as following:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

it tells me: " No module named tqdm "

i installed it with:

```
pip install tqdm
```

It has been installed successfully but i still have the same message: " No Module named tqdm ".

Comment: Could you check that `pip` and `python` use the same python installation? You can run `which pip` and `which python` to check that.

Answer (score 4):

I see that you've got this tagged as python 3. Could be your system's default installation of python is version 2.

Try `sudo pip3 install tqdm`.

Make sure you're running your script in version 3. `python3 ./example.py`

Comment: i did py -3 ex.py           but i'm still getting the same message

Comment: Yes, but did you install `tqdm` through the correct `pip`? Ensure you've done `pip3 install tqdm` not `pip install tqdm`

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. Installing via pip3 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not executing your .py file in a virtual environment.

If you are, all you have to do is activate the virtual environment and install it there.

change directory to where you have installed your virtual environment

cd .../bin

```
# this activates virtual environment
source activate
```

then

```
#install through pip
pip install tqdm
```

Comment: Is there a final solution to this error. I am getting the same error even after installing tqdm module. I use R and am using Reticulate package of R to access python code.